# Pandas series: Only keep the first entry that contains a given character (comma)

Tags: python, pandas

I scraped a table of SEC filings and extract a specific row as a pandas Series.

The tables are not very standardized in their formatting which makes scraping quite hard as unwanted information is extracted as well.

Take for example the following series I scraped from a table:

```
series = {'A': "3,360,003|", 'B': "(17) |", 'C': "16.8|"}
series = pd.Series(data=series, index=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

The only information that is relevant for me is the one that contains commas. Is there a way to remove all other entries of the series that doesn't contain commas?

There may be cases where there is more than one entry with commas, e.g.

```
series = {'A': "3,360,003|", 'B': "(17,424,32) |", 'C': "16.8|"}
series = pd.Series(data=series, index=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

in this case, the first entry that contains commas should be kept while all other should be removed.

Help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to work with Series methods, the approach would be:

```
series[series.str.contains(',')].iloc[0]
```

However, this requires checking all elements, just to keep one.

A much more efficient approach (depending on the exact data, there might be edge case where this isn't true), would be to use a `filter` and `next` to get the first element. This is more that 100 times faster on the provided example.

```
next(filter(lambda x: ',' in x, series))
```

Output: `'3,360,003|'`

Answer (score 0):

Use `.str.contains()` as a boolean indexer;

```
s = series[series.str.contains(',', na=False)]
```

Comment: Thanks. Any ideas how to handle the case when there are multiple entries with commas? In this case, all entries and not just the first one will be kept using this approach I guess.

Comment: With this method, all the cells with a comma will be stored in `s`. You can than extract the first value with `s.iloc[0]` I believe.

Comment: You could iterate over the cells until you find the first one containing a comma, but it won't be as efficient.